# Facebook API definitions explained

Tags: facebook, api, definition

I have the list of definitions for fields in the Facebook API.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/
The definitions are a brief and not explained. Is there a more detailed description of these somewhere? Specifically:
What is the difference between 'page_posts_impressions' and 'page_impressions'? 
I see that the 2nd is larger than the 1st. What other kind of page impression would a user get that is not in their feed?
Also, how are organic and viral defined? 
I thought that organic might be generated by the page's postings and viral might be generated by those posting stories about the page.
So I thought that organic + viral = total 
I can see on some days this is true but not on others.
Thanks
John

Answer (score 0):

From the page you linked:
`page_posts_impressions` -  The number of impressions that came from all of your posts
`page_impressions` - The total number of impressions seen of any content associated with your Page

The second includes places users were exposed to your page other than via posts the page itself made, including a user's friends writing on the page wall, sharing a link to the page, etc